# RadioButton: align 3 buttons with background horizontally

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-radiogroup

I'm having a problem right now.
I have a situation in which I need to display 3 buttons, button only one can be activated at the time.
I used to use "ImageButton", handling the clicked/unclicked state by myself.
But, I chose to switch it as a RadioGroup, because it what this kind oh behaviour should be handled by.
I want to do this :

- The 3 radio buttons have to be on a same line.
- **The proportions of the pictures used as background have to stay the same**, no matter the device.
- If possible, I'd like the buttons to occupy the same percentage of horizontal space no matter the device.**

I've tried, weight properties, alignParentLeft, right, hard-sized, but can't find a clean solution.

Can you please help me?

Here are the buttons:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/mobiprint_mod_radio_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_tag"
        android:layout_width="96dip"
        android:layout_height="68dip"
        android:background="@drawable/tag_on"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_pe"
        android:layout_width="96dip"
        android:layout_height="68dip"
        android:background="@drawable/pe_off"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_a7"
        android:layout_width="96dip"
        android:layout_height="68dip"
        android:background="@drawable/a7_off"
        android:button="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Please paste RadioGroup start tag with the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Since `RadioGroup` inherits from `LinearLayout`, you can use **weights** on the `RadioButtons`.
In your `Radiogroup`, set the orientation to be horizontal, as you would do with a `LinearLayout`.

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_tag"
    android:layout_height="68dip"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/tag_on"
    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
/>

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_pe"
    android:layout_height="68dip"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/pe_off"
    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
/>

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio_a7"
    android:layout_height="68dip"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/a7_off"
    android:button="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
/>
```

I removed those attributes which belong to `RelativeLayout`.

Note: the weights are all **1** and the widths are all **0dp**.
This is intentional.

Comment: Hello and thank you!

That way, I have my 3 buttons, but since the Height is fixed, and the width change because of the weigth value, the scale of the pictures used as background for each button will not be respected.
Do you have an idea for that?
Thanks!

Comment: backgrounds, by definition, are scaled to match the container size. If you want a fixed image, consider using the `button` attribute, instead: `android:button="@drawable/a7_off"`

Comment: Tried it... This way, the picture I want to use as my button, is cropped when the screen is not wide enough. I would have wanted that, if the screen become too small, my picture height decrease with its width.

Answer (score 0):

try to put below code. 
You need to define Orientation of radiogroup to horizontal and apply `weightsum` as well as apply `layout_weight` according to your convenience .

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/mobiprint_mod_radio_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_tag"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:text="option A" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_pe"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:text="option B" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio_a7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.33"
        android:text="option C" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: Hello and Thanks for your help,

The problem is, this way, my button height will always be 60dp. But, as, because of the "Weight" value, the Width of them will change, the scale for the background of each button will not be maintained :/

Do you have an idea?

Comment: If you are designing application for Single static screen you can use Relative layout and simply Drag and drop your radio button according to your need. otherwise for multiple screen set weight according to your Convenience . it would be helpful if you can share image what you exactly wants to design ..

Answer (score 0):

- Set Radio Group width to match_parent or in dip whatever width you want
- Add View (dummy view) in between two radio buttons i.e between 1st and 2nd & between 2nd and 3rd, with android:layout_weight="1"

  ```
  <RadioGroup
      android:id="@+id/mobiprint_mod_radio_group"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <RadioButton
          android:id="@+id/radio_tag"
          android:layout_width="96dip"
          android:layout_height="68dip"
          android:background="@drawable/tag_on"
          android:button="@android:color/transparent" />

      <View
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1" />

      <RadioButton
          android:id="@+id/radio_pe"
          android:layout_width="96dip"
          android:layout_height="68dip"
          android:background="@drawable/pe_off"
          android:button="@android:color/transparent" />

      <View
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1" />

      <RadioButton
          android:id="@+id/radio_a7"
          android:layout_width="96dip"
          android:layout_height="68dip"
          android:background="@drawable/a7_off"
          android:button="@android:color/transparent" />
  </RadioGroup>
  ```
- Space can also be used in place of View

  ```
     <Space
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1"/>
  ```